# SQL JOINING, Which is the best join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to collate data from three tables.

`tableA`, `tableB` and `tableC`. Table A is my main table containing the most data I want to pull.

Table A joins to Table B via `a.id` and `b.new_id`. However, Table C does not have any association to Table A and joins only through Table B: `b.board_id` and `c.board_id`.

Which is the best way to join these tables so that the variables will represent table A?

I can connect tables A and B like this:

`SELECT * FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.new_id` and the variables are fine. But when I try to add TableC the variables shown are that of TableC, not TableA.

Some of the tables contain identical column names. How would I join all three?

Comment: It all depends what you want to achieve. Maybe C has a many to 1 relationship to B?

Comment: I need 4 from A, 3 from B and 2 from C.

Comment: How many rows do you want returned? The basic join would be like in the answers, but if you for instance want to group B's and C's results to A, you need a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.new_id join tableC c on c.board_id=b.board_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.col1 as a_col1, a.col2 as a_col2, . . .
FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN
     tableB b
     ON a.id = b.new_id left join
     tablec c
     on b.board_id = c.board_id;
```

You don't have to create a separate name for all columns, you only need to do it for the ones with duplicates.